Berry curvature with Hermitian matrix interpretation
In my calculation for some effect I get terms that are proportional to
\begin{equation}
i\epsilon^{\mu \nu}\langle \partial_{\mu} \, u_n(k) | M(k) | \partial_\nu \, u_n(k) \rangle 
\end{equation}
where $\partial_\mu:=\frac{\partial}{\partial k_\mu}$, $M(k)$ is a Hermitian matrix and $u_n(k)$ is the cell-periodic bloch state for band $n$.

Is it possible to relate this term to the normal Berry curvature? Can I even interpret this expression as a curvature?

I am also interested in integrating this expression over the first BZ. Would I expect to get an integer (Chern-Gauss-Bonet theorem)?


